# How Can I refresh the View after I change application locale to RTL language problematically without restarting the activity

Tags: android, localization

In my activity I change locale programatically to RTL language. After that I want my layout to refresh according to RTL locale without restarting the activity.

Here is the code for that :

```
public void setLocale()

{
    String arr[] = LangCode.split("_");
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    DisplayMetrics dm = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    Locale locale = new Locale(arr[0], arr[1]);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.setLocale(locale);
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, dm);

}
```

I have tried to invalidate the view after that but with no success.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

    findViewById(R.id.intro_lang_ll).invalidate();

    findViewById(R.id.intro_lang_ll).requestLayout();

}
```

I want my view should mirror itself as soon as I change the locale without restarting the activity.

Comment: call recreate(); in your setLocale() method of your Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I do not want to recreate my activity. Any other suggestion ??

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refresh your whole Activity then you can use invalidate() as follows :

```
public void invalidate ()
```

It invalidate the whole view.

If the view is visible, onDraw(Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. 
To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

Comment: As I mention earlier I have tried both invalidate and  requestLayout on the parent linear layout but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

It works for me .. without delay